# Content merging AEM

Tags: aem

We're looking for a solution on how to best deal with the situation where multiple authors are working on the same page. If the first author pushes in the content, the second should have a way to merge it when he tries to publish. Launches appears to be a way to take care of this but it doesn't seem to be handling content merging. Is there any way an author can view the diff(and or do merge) of the content that might have been pushed by another author while they were working concurrently ?

Please help with any pointers.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: As I couldn't find any pointer, I was trying to read the JCR structure of the two versions of the page and trying to do a diff. But this doesn't appear to be a good solution. There's got to be something out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page modifications happen in real time to the underlying structure. They also happen at as small a level as possible.i.e. If you go into a text area and modify the text there, the text node is changed on the server, you aren't saving the entire page.

The only way that person A could interfere with what person B is doing is if they were working on the exact same area of the page. Which, honestly is a process issue. I say this because the answer to your question is that there is nothing out of the box to handle this type of scenario and if you are on 6.0 or higher and looking at the JCR3. JCR3 handles this far worse than the older version did. Last time I checked it didn't support nodes at all

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Bailey said, AEM OOB allow multiple users to edit same page in real time, though if multiple users are working on same node will be a reason of conflict. Such cases can be managed by defining a process like:
1. Take a lock of page and edit page or
2. Create versions of page and publish versions